# Does statifier/manual compile has lower c++ static executable size than Ermine?

Tags: c++, cross-compiling, executable

I've had a lot of troubles compiling static executable of my c++ code and i finally managed to do it with the use of Ermine, but after it i was told that 50mb is too big size for executable and i should reduce it if i can. Should i expect for lower executable size if i compile with statifier or do it manually with terminal?

P.S.: yes, i know, that i can compile and compare the sizes, but the problem is i need to compile 32 bit executable on 64 bit machine, so i'll spend plenty lot of time trying to do that.

Comment: What's Ermine? 50mb is small. What's statifier?  It's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @RichardCritten Ermine: http://www.magicermine.com/index.html
statifier: http://statifier.sourceforge.net